# Mapping values from application.yml to Java record class but value is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-record

My spring boot version is `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.1.2")`.

In `application.yml` I have defined those properties:

```
machine:
  product:
    port: 6443
    location:
      foo: "loc-1"
      bar: "loc-2"
```

I would like to create a `record` to associate with these properties, so I tried:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "machine")
public record MachineProperties(Product productProperties) {
    public record Product(Location locationProperties) {
        public record Location(String foo, String bar) {

        }
    }
}
```

I inject the above class to another one:

```
@Component
public class Other {
  private final MachineProperties machineProperties;

    @Autowired
    public Other(MachineProperties machineProperties) {
        this.machineProperties = machineProperties;
    }
}
```

But at runtime, the breakpoint shows me `productProperties` inside `machineProperties` is null. Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide the entire `MachineProperties` class?

Comment: @MaksimEliseev I am usingJava `record`, there is no class. The `public record MachineProperties(...)` is showing in my post.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expect this - I sleep on the go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with naming fields in the `MachineProperties` record class.

If you want to use properties named `product` and `location`, the fields must have the same name.

The following code works well:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "machine")
public record MachineProperties(Product product) {
    public record Product(Location location) {
        public record Location(String foo, String bar) {

        }
    }
}
```

From the naming point of view, I think using `productProperties` and `locationProperties` inside a property container that already has "properties" in its name is overkill. So you just need to rename these fields.